# Why `ltsc2022` cannot be used with gke-windows-tool on GCP?

Tags: windows, docker, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build a windows image using cloudbuild with `gke-windows-tool` but it seems that `ltsc2022` is not supported ! why ?
Here is the error message on the cloudbuild

```
us-docker.pkg.dev/gke-windows-tools/docker-repo/gke-windows-builder:latest
Starting Windows multi-arch container builder
picked-versions flag has unsupported Windows Server versions: ltsc2022
```

here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
timeout: 3600s
steps:
- name: 'us-docker.pkg.dev/gke-windows-tools/docker-repo/gke-windows-builder:latest'
  args:
  - --container-image-name
  - 'europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/windows/image-name:latest'
  - --versions
  - 'ltsc2022'
```

Here is the documentation I'm following https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/building-windows-multi-arch-images

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [GKE node images](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#available_node_images):

- [Windows Server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#windows-server)

  - [Windows Server LTSC with containerd (`windows_ltsc_containerd`)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#windows-server)
    (Supports both LTSC2022 and LTSC2019 node images)
  - [Windows Server LTSC with Docker (`windows_ltsc`)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#windows-server) (Unsupported in GKE version 1.24 and later. Unsupported for Windows Server LTSC2022.)

If you need to use Windows Server 2022, you need to [create a cluster using Windows Server node pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster-windows) as this use Windows Server Long-Term Servicing Channel (LTSC) node image.

You can also check [Containerd node images](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/using-containerd) for additional information.

Here's an example on how to create a Windows Server 2022 node pool:

```
gcloud container node-pools create node_pool_name \
    --cluster=cluster_name \
    --image-type=WINDOWS_LTSC_CONTAINERD \
    --windows-os-version=ltsc2022
```

Please be advised that in GKE version `1.24` and later, images with the Docker runtime are unsupported. Migrate to images with the containerd runtime before you upgrade to GKE `1.24`. To learn more about this change, see [Migrating from Docker to containerd](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/docker-containerd).

Comment: I already have a node pool with this image type, but still need to build my windows image before deploying it on GKE what do you suggest for the workflow ? as you know we can only use docker to build the image

Comment: I understand that however based on the [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/windows/intro/#containerd), containerd is the only supported container runtime for Kubernetes nodes that run Windows, including Windows Server 2022 as GKE is based on the Kubernetes deployed on Google's infrastructure. I would suggest to file this as a [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/sig-windows/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-issues-and-feature-requests) if this option is needed for your current infrastructure.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question, I'm actually going to use WINDOWS_LTSC_CONTAINERD on gke, so there is no problem with the containerd part, as I also do for linux arch images, I build the docker images that at the end I run on containerd VMs, But for windows I'm not able to build the docker image with gke-windows-tool for ltsc-2022

Comment: Based on the documentation you provided, GKE version 1.15 and 1.16 support Windows Server 1809 and 1909 respectively. If you encounter this error this means that your GKE version is higher than what's recommended in the documentation. I've mentioned it in my answer that if GKE 1.24 or later does not support Windows Docker runtime. Additional information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/docker-containerd#docker_and_containerd_node_images).